# SharePoint On-Premise over Internet

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Deployed SharePoint 2016 On-Premise Site. I would like to know how I can set it up to be accessible online. I have a Public IP Address.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a development question, try asking on [superuser](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Do you have domain?

Comment: Yes i do have a domain

Answer (score 0):

most likely you just need to open it up on your firewalls and have your IP public better with DNS